# Update database with two array parameters

Tags: php, sqlite

I´m trying to update my database with information that is send via a form.
My problem is that i don´t get how I can loop both arrays at the same. I have tried nesting foreach-loops with no success.

I then have this to work with

```
$display = $_POST["show"] ?? "";
$id = array_keys($_POST["show"]);

if ($action == "submit") {
foreach ($display as $key => $value) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE picture SET display = ? WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bindParam($display, $id)
        $stmt->execute();
}
 }
```

Comment: Where is set $id in your bindparam function?

Comment: I guess `$display` is an array, so you can't bind it.

Comment: `bindParam` binds __one__ param, not two and more.

Comment: both $display and $id is arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over array and get keys and values  at the same time:

```
$display = $_POST["show"] ?? [];

// Also you can check if `$display` is not empty
if ($action == "submit" && $display) {
    // prepare statement ONCE
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE picture SET display = ? WHERE id = ?");
    foreach ($display as $key => $value) {
        // execute statement as many times as you want with your params
        $stmt->execute([$value, $key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem because my id is inside they $key?

Comment: Correct, your id is in `$key` variable.

Answer (score 1):

If I saw correctly this is what you want:

```
<?php

    try {
        $display = isset($_POST['show']) ? $_POST['show'] : [];
        if ($action === 'submit' && !empty($display)) {
            $db->beginTransaction();
            $stmt = $db->prepare('
                UPDATE picture
                SET display = :display
                WHERE id = :id;
            ');
            foreach ($display as $id => $show) {
                $stmt->bindParam(':display', $show);
                $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            $db->commit();
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
       $db->rollBack();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, I marked the above post correctly because it solved my problem and was sent first. I'm also a beginner so it's hard for me to decide which one is "most" right.

Comment: Its ok, the main thing here is that you've found solution, this is just another approach, but you should use transactions for this kind of thing :-)